# How to make shortcut tile in start screen for Windows phone 7.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am working on a `windows phone app` & the app almost completed but I don't know how to shortcut tile for my wondows phone **7.0** app. which will **in start screen**. and when user pin that tile then my app will be opend.

and also I want to ask that can I use ShellTile in Windows phone 7.0? I think it's available in above 7.0 version

I found some code at msdn--->

`ShellTileSchedule SampleTileSchedule = new ShellTileSchedule();

........// some code`

but it's not worthed

does anyone have knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1):

Its called secondary tiles. Please refer this article and it will explain you very cleary.

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-add-and-remove-secondary-tiles-in-windows-phone-apps

Comment: thanks for answer, but its not ('StandardTileData') supported in wp 7.0, is there any other alternative or something else to make it supported(present) ?

Comment: @objectWithoutClass: This is supported in Windows Phone 7. Please Check The Sample On That Site. And Run On Emulator. Its Built For Windows Phone 7